# Why isn't a new collection being created in Cloud Firebase?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've returned a promise 'db' to access the collection. The collection doesn't exist yet because when I allow the user to signup Firebase should automatically create the collection. I then created a doc by passing in a id so when I save to that document it's going to create an autoid for that document.

I then set a property called email and then passed the email value to this. Now the document will have the same id as the users.

The problem is it isn't creating a new collection, any ideas?

```
   function signup(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass)(cred => {
    return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
      email: document.getElementById("email_field").value
    }).then
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);
    // ...
  });
}
```

Here is what I set in Cloud Firebase Rules and allowed documents to be created:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is not apparently doing anything with errors.  What code do you have in place to check for and report errors?  All we can see is the assignment of two variables.  Also, you have a dangling `then` that does nothing - do you need that?

Comment: Hi Doug, Thanks for the comment. I've removed the dangling 'then' and added a way to check for errors. I've updated the code above with these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to see any errors when calling the set method, I'd suggest you to use the [firebase authenticatio triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) (to keep some logic separated and not a lot of promises in your current implementation)in that way you can make reference to the user information with the parameter that is given at the trigger

PS: do you need that "then" at the db invocation? (as doug has mentioned on his comment)

Comment: You're right, I've removed the 'then' from the db invocation. Thanks for the help, I'll check the firebase auth triggers.